# Iterate through all tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for a way to iterate through all tables in a database.

I've come up with this so far:

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR 
    FOR
        SELECT 
        DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_CATALOG ='MyDB' 
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA=N'dbo'

OPEN MyCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @TableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM @TableName
    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @TableName
END 
CLOSE MyCursor
DEALLOCATE MyCursor
```

I get an error message in the While statement `The @TableName tablevariable must be declared` (translated from German).

I know there should be a variable of the type `TABLE` at `FROM @TableName`, but I haven't found how to do that, just how to declare new tables which I don't want.

Comment: You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables` instead of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Comment: You might want to do a web-search for sp_MSforeachtable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't `SELECT * FROM @TableName`

you will need to use Dynamic SQL

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to execute `select` on all your tables, you have to use dynamic SQL, as mentioned in other answer. Additionally, you don't need cursor at all! :)

Try this:

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = '';

select @sql = @sql + 'select * from ' + TABLE_CATALOG + '.' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ' ' 
from information_schema.tables

exec(@sql)
```